# JsonPath: find an element using a child element of an array

Tags: json, jsonpath, rest-assured-jsonpath, json-path-expression

I have array of objects and I'd like to find an object by using a condition using a child element.

For example, i want to get the value of the firstName if the value of phoneNumbers.type is "iPhone"

```
[{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "doe",
    "age": 26,
    "address": {
        "streetAddress": "naist street",
        "city": "Nara",
        "postalCode": "630-0192"
    },
    "phoneNumbers": [
        {
            "type": "iPhone",
            "number": "0123-4567-8888"
        },
        {
            "type": "home",
            "number": "0123-4567-8910"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "firstName": "Kevin",
    "lastName": "Johnson",
    "age": 26,
    "address": {
        "streetAddress": "naist street",
        "city": "Nara",
        "postalCode": "630-0192"
    },
    "phoneNumbers": [
        {
            "type": "android",
            "number": "0123-4567-8888"
        },
        {
            "type": "office",
            "number": "0123-4567-8910"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

I tried this but it doesn't match to anything.
$[?(@.phoneNumbers.type=='iPhone')].firstName